# MQTT Topic / property bag from Iot hub routed to event hub

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

my device publish a MQTT message to an Azure Iot hub and uses a topic with an additional property bag. The iot hub routes the message with the build-in routes and endpoints feature to an eventhub.

Is it possible, that an application which listens to the eventhub, could get the topic and property bag information from the message? And if it's possible, is each propertiy in the property bag accessible as property/value pair, or do I have to parse the topic property?

Thanks in advance!
Best regards,
Mananana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following screen snippets show the MQTT Client and the Azure Function as an EventHub trigger:

[image: MQTTBox]

and the consumer side:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
As I see, the topic _devices/Device10/message..._ is not added as a property. So if I like to have also the DeviceId (in your example "Device10"), I have to add it, also as a additional property _...id=12345&deviceId=Device10_, correct?

Comment: Have a look at the EventData class. There is a SystemProperties in the class, so add the following line to the AF to get more details: log.Info($"Label = {ed.SystemProperties["iothub-message-source"]}-{ed.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"]}/{ed.SequenceNumber}");

Comment: Thanks for your help!